# Observable Object breaks Codable protocol compliance in observing struct despite conforming to Codable (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I am confronted with a bit of a conundrum. I have an Observable Object MatrixStatus that is codable:

```
class MatrixStatus: ObservableObject, Codable{
    @Published var recalcTriggerd = false
    
    init(){}
    
    //Codable protocol
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
        case recalcTriggered
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(recalcTriggerd, forKey: .recalcTriggered)
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        recalcTriggerd = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .recalcTriggered)
    }
}
```

It is set up as an environment object by a View of a document. The document observes it and remains codable. However, if I observe it in a different struct, MatrixData, that is a property of the document, the MatrixData struct stops conforming to Codable

```
struct MatrixData: Codable, Equatable{
    @EnvironmentObject var calcStatus: MatrixStatus //triggers 'does not conform to codable'
    ...
```

Any suggestions how to solve, other than implementing the encode etc functions in MatrixData?

Thanks,

Lars

Comment: Why do you need an `@EnvironmentObject` in a `struct` that is not a view? You use  `@EnvironmentObject` in views to maintain a view model, not in data structs.

Comment: It also feels like a code smell to mix `ObservableObject` and `Codable` in the same type. Why do you want to encode your ViewModel as `Codable`? You should create simple model structs that conform to `Codable` and store/create those by the ViewModel, which conforms to `ObservableObject`.

Comment: I know it is convoluted. The view can trigger re-calculation in the matrixData property of the document which in turn cause downstream parts of the UI to crash. I would like to use  ```if !matrixStatus.recalcTriggerd{}``` to prevent those from being rendered. However, I need the matrixData to tell the UI that it is done and set recalcTriggerd back to false. I have tried an async for the recalculations approach but they do not seem supported in .onChange modifiers.

Comment: “@EnvironmentObject” shouldn’t be placed anywhere but a SwiftUI view